# Overall Stack Exchange card

Tags: support, profile-page, flair, combined-flair

How do you put a card like this on your profile?

[image]

Which groups all your Stack Exchange sites' reputation points, medals and icons.

---

Is there a minimum reputation check for an Icon to appear on the card?

Comment: The [meta-tag:user-card] is for user card which is the box opening when hovering over user name or avatar in posts.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks i didn't know that.

Comment: "Is there a minimum reputation check for an Icon to appear on the card" -- yes, 200.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click your name, then click "flair". You can paste that code in to your profile.

Comment: ..well that was simple thanks a lot

Comment: Actually when I post it I only see a stackoverflow icon. Do I have to reach a certain reputation on other sites for it to appear on my card ?

Comment: A minimum of 200 if I recall correctly.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk You can get a network wide flair from the bottom of the flair page or from your profile on [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com)